# How to prepared saturated salt solution (NaCl)?

Tags: aqueous-solution

What do they mean by "add 321 g saturated NaCl solution"? Description does not contain volume.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry SE! As NaCl solubility is [temperature-dependent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saline_water), more details are needed in the OP. I recommend posting the source of this quote to provide context.

Comment: If you know the density (i.e., mass divided by volume) it suffices to weigh the solution on a balance instead of using e.g., a graduated cylinder to record a volume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your description, I would suggest to add $\displaystyle\frac{\pu{321 g}}{\pu{1.1998 g cm^{-3}}} = \pu{267.5 mL}$ of saturated salt solution (assuming approx. $\pu{25 °C},$ ambient temperature).

A report *The Densities of Saturated Solutions of
NaCl and KCl from 10° to 105 °C* by U.S. Geological Survey ([PDF](https://pubs.usgs.gov/of/1984/0253/report.pdf)) contains a collection of density values for saturated NaCl solutions at various temperatures, of which I used the value at $\pu{25.37 °C}.$